# How to pass test status to it's teardown, through a fixture preferably

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a BaseTest class which has tear_down and I want to have inside tear_down a variable representing wether or not the test has failed.

I tried look at A LOT of older posts but I coulden't implement them as they were hooks or mixture of hook and fixture and something did not work on my end.

What is the best practice for doing that?

Last thing I've tried was -

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    # set a report attribute for each phase of a call, which can
    # be "setup", "call", "teardown"

    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
```

Then pass request fixture to teardown and inside use

```
has_failed = request.node.rep_call.failed
```

But request had no attributes at all, it was a method.
Also tried -

```
@pytest.fixture
def has_failed(request):
    yield

    return True if request.node.rep_call.failed else False
```

and pass it like that.

```
def teardown_method(self, has_failed):
```

And again, no attributes.

Isn't there a simple fixture to just do like request.test_status or something like that?

It's important that the teardown will have that bool parameter wether or not it failed and not do stuff outside the teardown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any super simple fixture offering the test report as a fixture. And I see what you mean: most examples of recording the test report are geared toward non-unittest use cases (including [the official docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures)). However, we can adjust these examples to work with unittest TestCases.

There appears to be a private `_testcase` attribute on the `item` arg passed to `pytest_runtest_makereport`, which contains the instance of the TestCase. We can set an attribute on it, which can then be accessed within `teardown_method`.

```
# conftest.py

import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()

    if report.when == 'call' and hasattr(item, '_testcase'):
        item._testcase.did_pass = report.passed
```

And here's a dinky little example TestCase

```
import unittest

class DescribeIt(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup_method(self, method):
        self.did_pass = None

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        print('\nself.did_pass =', self.did_pass)

    def test_it_works(self):
        assert True

    def test_it_doesnt_work(self):
        assert False
```

When we run it, we find it prints the proper test failure/success bool

```
$ py.test --no-header --no-summary -qs

============================= test session starts =============================
collected 2 items                                                             

tests/tests.py::DescribeIt::test_it_doesnt_work FAILED
self.did_pass = False

tests/tests.py::DescribeIt::test_it_works PASSED
self.did_pass = True


========================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.02s =========================
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I was looking for